# R: calculate absolute and relative difference between a set of variables and a reference var

Tags: r

I have a data frame, named dat, with following structure:

```
dat
    ref test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6
1  1565  1432  1299  1166  1033   900   767
2  1232  1117  1002   887   772   657   542
3  1417  1342  1267  1192  1117  1042   967
4   895  1115  1335  1555  1775  1995  2215
5  2150  1890  1630  1370  1110   850   590
6  1565  1432  1299  1166  1033   900   767
```

I would like to create a script which calculates, for each variable test1, test2, test3 (it would be great if the script could select all variables having a name starting with "test"), the absolute and the relative difference between testX and ref. 
The results should be a data frame as the following:

results

```
  test1_absdiff test2_absdiff test3absdiff test1_percdiff test2_percdiff test3percdiff
1          -133          -266         -399        -0.0850         -0.170        -0.255
2          -115          -230         -345        -0.0933         -0.187        -0.280
3           -75          -150         -225        -0.0529         -0.106        -0.159
4           220           440          660         0.246           0.492         0.737
5          -260          -520         -780        -0.121          -0.242        -0.363
6          -133          -266         -399        -0.0850         -0.170        -0.255
```

I can write the code to calculate a new variable, but i dont't know how to apply it to a set of variables, defined as having a common prefix ("test")

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, your `absdiff` columns do not represent the conventional semantics of absolute (`abs`) differences in your expected output. Secondly, if you are providing sample data, please do so by pasting the output of `dput(data)` such that we do not have to manually reproduce your data ourselves.

Throwing in a `data.table` solution for good measure.

**Code**

```
cols = colnames(dt)[colnames(dt) %like% 'test'] # ID test variables

dt[, (paste0(cols, '_diff')) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x - ref), .SDcols = cols]
dt[, (paste0(cols, '_pdiff')) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/ref - 1), .SDcols = cols]
```

**Output**

```
> dt
   ref test1 test2 test3 test1_diff test2_diff test3_diff test1_pdiff test2_pdiff test3_pdiff
1:  10     1     5     9         -9         -5         -1        -0.9  -0.5000000  -0.1000000
2:  20     2     6    10        -18        -14        -10        -0.9  -0.7000000  -0.5000000
3:  30     3     7    11        -27        -23        -19        -0.9  -0.7666667  -0.6333333
4:  40     4     8    12        -36        -32        -28        -0.9  -0.8000000  -0.7000000
```

**Data**

```
dt = data.table(
  ref = c(10,20,30,40),
  test1 = c(1,2,3,4),
  test2 = c(5,6,7,8),
  test3 = c(9,10,11,12)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dat=read.table(text="
    ref test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6
1  1565  1432  1299  1166  1033   900   767
2  1232  1117  1002   887   772   657   542
3  1417  1342  1267  1192  1117  1042   967
4   895  1115  1335  1555  1775  1995  2215
5  2150  1890  1630  1370  1110   850   590
6  1565  1432  1299  1166  1033   900   767",h=T)

k=which(grepl("test",colnames(dat)))

tmp1=dat[,k]-dat[,"ref"]
colnames(tmp1)=paste0(colnames(tmp1),"_absdiff")
tmp2=(dat[,k]-dat[,"ref"])/dat[,"ref"]
colnames(tmp2)=paste0(colnames(tmp2),"_percdiff")

round(cbind(tmp1,tmp2),3)

  test1_absdiff test2_absdiff test3_absdiff test4_absdiff test5_absdiff test6_absdiff test1_percdiff
1          -133          -266          -399          -532          -665          -798         -0.085
2          -115          -230          -345          -460          -575          -690         -0.093
3           -75          -150          -225          -300          -375          -450         -0.053
4           220           440           660           880          1100          1320          0.246
5          -260          -520          -780         -1040         -1300         -1560         -0.121
6          -133          -266          -399          -532          -665          -798         -0.085
  test2_percdiff test3_percdiff test4_percdiff test5_percdiff test6_percdiff
1         -0.170         -0.255         -0.340         -0.425         -0.510
2         -0.187         -0.280         -0.373         -0.467         -0.560
3         -0.106         -0.159         -0.212         -0.265         -0.318
4          0.492          0.737          0.983          1.229          1.475
5         -0.242         -0.363         -0.484         -0.605         -0.726
6         -0.170         -0.255         -0.340         -0.425         -0.510
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying these on data which I import from an excel file and it gives to me this error: Error in Ops.data.frame(dat[, k], dat[, "ref"]) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Comment: @MarianoCGiglio Hard to tell, if the data is in the same format as the one you posted in your question, it should work. Can you post a minimal example, where the code fails?

Comment: > tmp1=dat[,k]-dat[,"ref"]
Error in Ops.data.frame(dat[, k], dat[, "ref"]) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
> colnames(tmp1)=paste0(colnames(tmp1),"_absdiff")
Error in is.data.frame(x) : oggetto "tmp1" non trovato
> tmp2=(dat[,k]-dat[,"ref"])/dat[,"ref"]
Error in Ops.data.frame(dat[, k], dat[, "ref"]) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
> colnames(tmp2)=paste0(colnames(tmp2),"_percdiff")
Error in is.data.frame(x) : oggetto "tmp2" non trovato
> 
> round(cbind(tmp1,tmp2),3)
Error in cbind(tmp1, tmp2) : oggetto "tmp1" non trovato

Comment: @MarianoCGiglio I meant if you can provide a minimal example dataset, where this error occurs. But anyway, check if k is empty - that is if you have any variables with names that contain "temp", and check if you have a variable named "ref".

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("test")), list(absolutediff = ~ . - ref,
                                           relativediff = ~ ./ref - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, maybe you can do it like this:

```
dfref <- as.data.frame(rep(df[1],ncol(df)-1))
r <- cbind(df[-1] - dfref, df[-1]/dfref - 1)
colnames(r) <- c(paste0(colnames(df[-1]),"_absdiff"), paste0(colnames(df[-1]),"percdiff"))
```

then

```
> r
  test1_absdiff test2_absdiff test3_absdiff test4_absdiff test5_absdiff test6_absdiff test1percdiff test2percdiff test3percdiff test4percdiff
1          -133          -266          -399          -532          -665          -798   -0.08498403    -0.1699681    -0.2549521    -0.3399361
2          -115          -230          -345          -460          -575          -690   -0.09334416    -0.1866883    -0.2800325    -0.3733766
3           -75          -150          -225          -300          -375          -450   -0.05292872    -0.1058574    -0.1587862    -0.2117149
4           220           440           660           880          1100          1320    0.24581006     0.4916201     0.7374302     0.9832402
5          -260          -520          -780         -1040         -1300         -1560   -0.12093023    -0.2418605    -0.3627907    -0.4837209
6          -133          -266          -399          -532          -665          -798   -0.08498403    -0.1699681    -0.2549521    -0.3399361
  test5percdiff test6percdiff
1    -0.4249201    -0.5099042
2    -0.4667208    -0.5600649
3    -0.2646436    -0.3175723
4     1.2290503     1.4748603
5    -0.6046512    -0.7255814
6    -0.4249201    -0.5099042
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ref = c(1565L, 1232L, 1417L, 895L, 2150L, 1565L
), test1 = c(1432L, 1117L, 1342L, 1115L, 1890L, 1432L), test2 = c(1299L, 
1002L, 1267L, 1335L, 1630L, 1299L), test3 = c(1166L, 887L, 1192L, 
1555L, 1370L, 1166L), test4 = c(1033L, 772L, 1117L, 1775L, 1110L, 
1033L), test5 = c(900L, 657L, 1042L, 1995L, 850L, 900L), test6 = c(767L, 
542L, 967L, 2215L, 590L, 767L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```